# Can't call form_Load event because of "not declared" error, but the name is correct and the event is in the appropriate class

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to add a load event to a form so that the data on the form (pulled from a DB), will refresh after the user performs an add, delete, or update. Each of these functions is accessed by a click event. The form_Load event is the last line of code in the subroutine calling the click event.

I've made sure the name of the form matches the name in the Load event call, and I've made sure that the form isn't still named "Form1" elsewhere the code.

Here is the code used for each of my Load event calls:

```vb
Option Strict On

Public Class frmHome

    Private Sub mySub

        ' do something

        'Refresh frmHome to show new customer
        frmHome_Load(sender, e)

    End Sub
```

Here is the error message:

```vb
Error   BC30451 'frmHome_Load' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
```

Comment: Remove the code you have in `Form.Load`, make a method (Function) for that code so you can call it whenever you need it. Even in `Form.Load`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what Jimi is talking about:

```
Public Class frmHome

    Private Sub frmHome_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Foo()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Foo()
        ' ... code ...
    End Sub

    Private Sub mySub()
        ' do something

        Foo()
    End Sub

End Class
```